# How do I update the database values using update statement?

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to update `'company_name', 'company_add', 'price'` as primary key `'id'` but it shows me a `'something went wrong'` message along with an `'undefined id'` error. please help me!

```
<?php
include('data_conn.php');

if(isset($_POST['sub']))
{
    $comname=$_POST['cname'];
    $comadd=$_POST['cadd'];
    $pri=$_POST['price'];

    $query ="UPDATE login SET company_name=$comname,company_add=$comadd,price=$pri WHERE id=$id";
    $result = mysql_query($query);
    echo $result;
    if(!$result)
    {
        echo '<script language="javascript">';
        echo 'alert("something went Wrong...:("); location.href="edit.php"';
        echo '</script>';
    }else{
        echo '<script language="javascript">';
        echo 'alert("successfully updated!!!"); location.href="edit.php"';
        echo '</script>';
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: I can see $id in script...

Comment: `language="javascript"`? `mysql_query`? Some really outdated code.

Comment: $id is not accepting any id....but i am giving id=1; then it update successfully

Comment: mysql deprecated use mysqli or PDO

Comment: `$id` is not set. Use something like `$id=$_POST['id']` ;

Comment: Also, you're missing these: `'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using direct substitution values, you could use below methods to avoid sql injection.

You basically have two options to achieve this:

1. Using PDO (for any supported database driver):

   ```
   $stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM employees WHERE name = :name');

   $stmt->execute(array('name' => $name));

   foreach ($stmt as $row) {
       // do something with $row
   }
   ```
2. Using MySQLi (for MySQL):

   ```
   $stmt = $dbConnection->prepare('SELECT * FROM employees WHERE name = ?');
   $stmt->bind_param('s', $name);

   $stmt->execute();

   $result = $stmt->get_result();
   while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
       // do something with $row
   }
   ```

Please refer [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Answer (score 0):

You have to put the character values in single quotes:

```
$query ="UPDATE login SET company_name='$comname',company_add='$comadd',price=$pri WHERE id=$id";
```

**Stop** using deprecated `mysql_*` API. Use `mysqli_*` or `PDO` with prepared Statements.
Atleast use the error function, to get the error message.